# Comparing Two Constructions of the Same Async/Await Function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await

I am trying to determine if these two ways of setting up this section of a function are functionally equivalent - in terms of when the `forEach()` block runs.

NOTE: "Customer" here represents a Mongoose model.

Here's the first construction of the function:

```
  async processRecords() {
   // other code
    while (recordsProcessed < recordsTotalCount) {
      await Customer.find({
          updatedAt: {
            $gte: this.lastUpdateTime
          }
        })
        .limit(recordsPerRun)
        .skip(recordsProcessed)
        .exec((err, docs) => {
          docs.forEach((doc) => {
            this.next(doc);
          });
        });
     }
  }
```

And here's the second one:

```
  async processRecords() {
    // other code
    while (recordsProcessed < recordsTotalCount) {
      request.parameters.skip = recordsProcessed;
      request.parameters.limit = recordsPerRun;

      let docs = await request.find(Customer, {
        updatedAt: {
          $gte: this.lastUpdateTime
        }
      });
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        this.next(doc);
      });
    }
  }
```

Specifically, I'm curious if the `forEach()` block will run differently, or the same. For these two constructions of the function, will all the records be "found" first, and then the `forEach()` will run on each record?

Comment: there's no way to really know since you don't provide code for the `Customer` object. However, I will say, that `.forEach` will not await like you might think it will. Use a for of loop instead. That will honor async behavior

Comment: Here "Customer" represents a Mongoose model.

Comment: @Andrew Kim, I assume what you mean is that the `forEach()`might not process records in order, whereas a `for of` loop will. Is that what you're getting at? If so, I agree.

Comment: If `Customer.find` and `request.find(Customer ...` returns the same thing for docs, then yes. It all depends on what the Mongoose model is doing with its promise implementation